# Joining 3 tables on MySQL to sum sales and stock for a product

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

1. products (sku, price, priceOffer, etc)
2. stock (sku, branch, items)
3. sales_provider (sku, items, date)

The table products holds all the information about a product, except for stock or sales. Current stock is stored in the table stock, and has information about how many items are available on each branch. The table "sales_provider" stores how many items were sold each day for every product. The product ID is "sku".

Now, I'm trying to get with one query the product that:

1. Has generated the best profit (number of sales * offered price)
2. Is still available on stock

And, of course, I want to know how many items are still on stock and how many items were sold.

I'm trying a query like this:

```
select
    *
from
    (
        select
            p.*,
            sum(s.items) stock,
            sum(sp.items) sales,
            case when
                p.priceOffer < p.price
                and
                p.priceOffer > 0
            then
                p.priceOffer
            else
                p.price
            end finalPrice
        from
            products p
        join
            stock s
            on
            s.sku = p.sku
        join
            sales_provider sp
            on
            sp.sku = p.sku
        group by
            sku
    ) temp
where
    stock > 0
order by
    (finalPrice * sales) desc
limit 1;
```

But I'm having problems with that. Basically, I'm getting a huge sum of stock items ans sales_provider items, not the real amounts. Also, it's a slow query (it's taking about half a second with only 9,500 products).

I've been trying to modify it and I'm having doubts about the subquery being necessary, but I just can't nail it.

If someone can help me improve it and get the correct result, I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for any helpful comment.

Francisco

Comment: You're looking for the product that brought in the most gross revenue, correct?  To compute profit you'd need cost information.

Comment: @OllieJones: Yes, that's correct. The reason I'm not taking the original cost in the query is that all products have a fixed profit of 10%. Whenever there's a `priceOffer`, it's just informative but it's an offer from the provider and it still has the same profit of 10%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of query, you want to do the aggregations separately on `stock` and `sales_provider`.  Otherwise, you will generate a cartesian product between the two tables for a given item.

Try this:

```
select p.sku, (salesitems*offeredprice) as profit, stockitems, salesitems
from products p left join
     (select sku, SUM(items) as stockitems
      from stock
      group by sku
     ) s
     on p.sku = s.sku left join
     (select sku, SUM(items) as salesitems
      from sales_provider sp
      group by sku
     ) sp
     on p.sku = sp.sku
where p.stockitems > 0
order by profit desc
```

This assumes that `product(sku)` is unique.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! Now the data is correct and the query time is 30% of the original time. :-)